# Opening .rData files from anywhere when installing R without admin privileges on Windows 7

Tags: r

I've installed R like this many times but it always seems I  blunder through some step so that I can open .rdata files from anywhere. Right now I can open Rgui.exe (my preferred approach) where it is installed (C:\Users\myname\Documents\R\R-2.15.3\bin\i386) but in no way can I open a .rData file.

I click the .rData and "open with..." but directing it to open r with the above path will not open the file. What is the subtle step to get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "will not open"? Does `R` start up, either the GUI or the command-line version?  Why do you have files named `.rData` in different locations?  That's risky, as you won't know which contains which data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I click on the `.rData` file located in some place, a command line will pop up for a moment saying the path and saying "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory."

Comment: What's your operating system?  I Googled some KB articles like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156276  or this thread http://www.oraxcel.com/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1218443170 .  But if CMD.exe is trying to start up, then clearly you've got `.rdata` files associated with cmd.exe (or R_CMD) rather than the Rgui.  One other thing: did you hand-type the path, or did you select the R-cmd icon via the "browse" option in the "open with" dialog box?

Comment: The operating system is Windows 7 64-bit. I select Rgui using the "browse" option in the "open with" dialog box to get right to the correct path and the "R for Windwos front end" button is available. When I click this button in the "open with" box it still pops open a cmd window (now blank) which immediately closes.

Comment: I'm stumped then, as I can't reproduce that. On my win7-64, I can open with either the i386 (32bit) or the x64 R term app.  The only other remote possibility is that some directory in your R-path is read-only and thus blocking some part of the launch sequence.

Comment: Just curious. Is your R installed in C:\Program Files\... or is it installed in C:\Users\... I was just thinking this makes a difference since my C:\Program Files is read only.

Comment: One other point of interest is that it worked well when I ran R-2.15.2. Then I uninstalled it and installed R-2.15.3. This is when it stopped working.

Comment: alright, I found a temporary fix. I just uninstalled R-2.15.3 and downloaded R-2.15.2 and now it's all good. I have the R for Windows **Gui** front end button back (strangely, only the cmd option was present in the 2.15.3!?) and it works when I click on a `.rData` file.